# ModelState.Isvalid throwing exception when changing the mvc routing id as string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I changed my route config file id as string

```
   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Agent_default",
            "Agent/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }

        );
    }
```

Now I can get my url as I expected like this http://localhost:43425/Agent/Accounts/Edit/A64h9lStdffgt

But I am getting an Exception when I am saving the model .

Throwing an Exception ModelState.Isvalid - False

Saying that : The value 'A64h9lStdffgt' is not valid for Id. How to resolve this one? How ModelState.Isvalid works? Why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Does your model have a property named `id`? If so, what is it's type?

Comment: id type is integer,i have other parameter 'Number' which is string. I am passing the 'Number' to the url instead of 'Id'.

Comment: You are passing `id` because your route is `"Agent/{controller}/{action}/{id}",` Your need to change the route definition to `"Agent/{controller}/{action}/{number}",` or change the name of your models `id` property to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On behalf of @Stephen Muecke:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Agent_Custom",
        "Agent/{controller}/{action}/{number}",
        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", number = "" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Agent_default",
        "Agent/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```